# Is there a way to redirect content loaded with JQuery ui tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a situation where the ajax loaded content of a JQuery ui Tab...

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

...needs to have a part of the html that is loaded when a tab is clicked
to populate a div in another part of the page.

Note: that the tabs are working fine... I just need to make just one part go somewhere else.

Perhaps something like this... But i can't find in the documentation the object to search.

```
$(".tabsZ").tabs({
    load: function (event, ui) {
        var mmm = ?????.find("div#messageToShow");
        if (mmm.length != 0) {
            $('#divMessage').html(mmm);
            ?????.html('');
        }
    }
});
```

????? = the object to search.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs in JQueryUI are just `<div>`'s on the same page but rendered horizontally. So all you have to do, is poke whatever information you have into your own `<div>` or `<span>` somewhere on the same page, even if it's on another tab.

So, in one tab you determine what the new text is (possibly via an onclick handler or whatever):

```
<div id="sourcediv"> Here's whatever was rendered </div>
...
var newtext = $('#sourcediv').html()
```

Then you poke it into say `targetdiv` even when that's on a different tab and clear the contents of your source:

```
<div id="targetdiv"> This will be overwritten from sourcediv </div>
$('#targetdiv').html(newtext);
$('#sourcediv').html('');
```

Comment: That is the part I already have up and running.
What I am needing is the object to do the JQuery on.
(Note that this tabs are being loaded form the ajax function of the tabs,)

Comment: Well isn't that `$('#sourcediv').html()`? Else I'm sorry but misunderstanding the question...